# Incomplete and weird output from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, output

```
Reduce[
a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0 &&
a + b + c > 0 &&
a >= d, 
{a, b, c, d}]
```

Returns the following solutions

```
(a == 0 && ((b == 0 && c > 0 && d == 0) || (b > 0 && c >= 0 && d == 0))) 
|| (a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && 0 <= d <= a)
```

I have no problems with the solution on the second line, the first line have spawned two questions.

1. Why isn't `d == 0` extracted from the OR statement, like so :

   ```
   (a == 0 && d == 0 && ((b == 0 && c > 0) || (b > 0 && c >= 0))
   ```
2. Now, let's simplify the problem to address the second question:

   ```
   Reduce[
   a >= 0 && b >= 0 &&
   a + b > 0, {a, b}]
   ```

   Returns the following solutions

   ```
   (a == 0 && b > 0)
   (a > 0 && b >= 0)
   ```

   But not these two:

   ```
   (a > 0 && b == 0)
   (a >= 0 && b > 0)
   ```

   Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) has a contract to provide the simplest possible answer. You can always simplify the output of [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce):

```
Reduce[
    a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0 && d >= 0 &&
    a + b + c > 0 &&
    a >= d, 
    {a, b, c, d}
];
Simplify @ %
```

> (a == 0 && 
>      d == 0 && ((b == 0 && c > 0) || (b > 0 && c >= 0))) || (0 <= d <= a && 
>      b >= 0 && c >= 0 && a > 0)

which returns what you wanted. As for your second question, your proposed additional solutions are already included. Here's the [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) output:

```
r = Reduce[
    a >= 0 && b >= 0 &&
    a + b > 0, {a, b}
]
```

> (a == 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b >= 0)

One can show that your additional "solutions" are already included as follows:

```
FullSimplify[(a > 0 && b == 0) && !r]
FullSimplify[(a >= 0 && b > 0) && !r]
```

> False
>
> False